# text in upper right corner of title page in beamer

Tags: beamer

I need to add a small text in the title page at the upper right corner. Does anyone know how to do that? I tried to search online, but I couldn't do that.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eso-pic`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\title{A Presentation}
\author{Somebody}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \AddToShipoutPictureFG*{
    \AtPageUpperLeft{\put(0,-10){\makebox[\paperwidth][r]{Some text}}}  
    }%
    \maketitle
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note the `*` in `\AddToShipoutPictureFG*{` which puts the content in only the title page and on fore ground (for background, put `\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{`)

You can also use the beast called `tikz` (this needs 2-3 compilation runs)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\title{A Presentation}
\author{Somebody}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
      \node[anchor=north east] at (current page.north east){Some text};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \maketitle
  \end{frame}
  \begin{frame}
    Some text
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```